# What does "Affected items" mean in the threat report of Windows 10 Microsoft Defender scan?

Tags: windows-10, security, csv, trojan

After conducting a full scan on my Fujitsu Windows 10 laptop today (Nov. 01, 2022), I got informed of this threat: Trojan:HTML/CryptoExtortBTC.A (I do not do anything about cryptocurrency. This seems to be a new malware with the only search result containing its name being [this link](https://malwarefixes.com/threats/trojanhtml-cryptoextortbtc-a/). However, its name sounds similar to "Trojan:HTML/CryptoStealBTC", which seems to be [discussed in Dell forum as a false positive](https://www.dell.com/community/Virus-Spyware/Dell-Update-triggers-CryptoStealBTC-warning-with-Microsoft/td-p/8158570). However, as described above, my computer is not from Dell.)

Details: This program is dangerous and executes commands from an attacker.

With affected items:
file: C:$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-2502570151-1049385929-2667336535-500$R9PV95S.csv

file: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\records_30d.csv

After asking Windows Security to remove the threat (the current status is "Removed"), I searched for both items in the respective location, but cannot find them. Are these items also removed along with the threat itself? (Also if the items were not removed, is it OK for me to open the items without causing damage?)

What does it mean when the affected items are only the csv files? Does it mean that the attacker did not access e.g. the password saved in the browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when Defender removes the threat, it is removed from your system. However, it also may have gone into Defender Quarantine. That is the normal process.  If the threat is very severe, it may just be deleted, but look in Quarantine and see if the file is there. It likely is.

I have seen it both ways:  entirely deleted or quarantined.

Comment: Thank you for your information. But my main question still remains: What does it mean when the affected items are only the csv files? Are they the only ones affected by the trojan? How are they affected? What is the implication?

Comment: If the file is badly infected (any type of file), then WD may just delete it.That is about all we can say at this point.